# Monolithic to Microservcies architecture

Tags: .net-core, microservices

My company has a .NET project which serves following use cases

1. It listens on a WebSocket Port with certificate based client authentication.
2. It listens on another WebSocket Port with authorization header based client authentication.
3. It listens on a TCP Port with certificate based client authentication.

On the above three ports different set of client devices are connected.

Now my company wants to convert this application in .NET Core so that this can be deployed on Linux servers to save the deployment cost. As an architect I am thinking in the direction of adopting microservices architecture along with migrating the application in .NET Core. So I am thinking that the above application can be break down into three microservices based on the above use cases.

AFAIK microservices architecture means breaking down your application into smaller services which serves a particular use case. So breaking this complete application into three different microservices is correct or not. 
My organization is very new to micro services architecture.I just want to know that whether this thinking is correct or not as per architecture.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What you need to be really careful with is that your micro service doesn’t turn into a distributed monolith. If all services are independent of each other and just react to events, micro services are very feasible. However, if they depend on each other’s data—a good sign here is if you start doing RPC calls to another service—you really have a distributed monolith and the architecture is not a good fit.

Comment: My all services are independent of each other.

Comment: "AFAIK microservices architecture means breaking down your application into smaller services which serves a particular use case". This understanding is not correct. Usually one use-case spans several microservices. There could be a couple of way to define boundaries. The most important one is business domain. The second one could be some scalability requirements. You may want to scale on some very specific operations and you may need to create a separate ms for those. The third one could be scale on the development team to give freedom to teams to implements/release their own things.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I'd try to break things down based on business domains (or business capabilities) instead of technical reasons.

A good place to start might be reading about domain driven design and bounded contexts - see [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) - there's some good further reading at the end of that link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are thinking in right direction.
Here are my suggestion-
you should go for .NET Core and Docker for implementing your Microservices in a better way.
There can be multiple cases when you will go for docker container in this scenario-
1: Run the same image in multiple containers
2: Manage different Containers
3: Run the same image in multiple environments
4: Tag and Run image with different versions

And other reason to go for micro services with docker-
Microservices are smaller in size
Microservices are easier to develop, deploy, and debug, because a fix only needs to be deployed onto the microservice with the bug, instead of across the board
Microservices can be scaled quickly and can be reused among different projects
Microservices work well with containers like Docker
Microservices are independent of each other, meaning that if one of the microservices goes down, there is little risk of the full application shutting down.

You do more research on the same and easily go for micro services architecture.

Comment: Yes i know that I will got the benefit of docker and kubernetes from this, but I am also concerned about the cons, like how it is different from managing 3 different monolithic applications. On again deep thinking over it I found that shall it introduced code redundancy as only the connection mechanism and authentication mechanism of my client devices is different, rest all application protocol is same.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be answering your question, but I thought it could be useful, especially in light of the fact that your organization is very new to micro-services.

I would recommend to carefully evaluate the advantages and especially disadvantages (complexity) that micro-services architecture introduces.

Just a few examples of things that you will need to think about are log aggregation, communication between services (sync vs async), E2E and integration tests, eventual consistency, etc. Obviously you may end up not having to deal with some of these, but all of them do become a lot more complicated with micro-services.

There should be good business justification to take on the additional complexity (=cost).

Answer (score 0):

Microservices shouldn't be measured on how small enough but how autonomous and independent they are. Microservices are great to be designed around business and domain context and mentioned in details [Identifying domain boundires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/identify-microservice-domain-model-boundaries)

Since you are starting to build microservices in .Net core why not consider severless microservices ? You have plenty on options in major clouds (AWS,Azure) to build serverless microservices. Serverless are quicker to build and you get generous free tier and you don't have to manage clusters. Is there specific reason you would want to use Kubernetes? you can read more about cloud native and servlerss here [Design Cloud native and Serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/leverage-serverless-functions)